# Does anyone know how to solve IP canonicalization with shopify platform?

Tags: seo, ip, shopify

My website is in shopify platform, As per the SEO checkup tools i found the ip canonicalization test error. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Is your store on a subdomain (nb: www... ) or root domain name (example.com)

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error and the page where the error throws up?

Comment: @HymnZ In the SEO site checkup report i found the error - "Your site's IP " IP Address" does not redirect to your site's domain name. This could cause duplicate content problems if a search engine indexes our site under both its IP and domain name."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue mentioned cannot be solved. All store's on Shopify use **myshopify.com** domain as the primary lookup point. It's the same case for every third-party host (unless specified). That is why you configure the setting in the C-Panel of your domain registrar.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code to your `.htaccess` file then test again it will be resolve

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^000\.000\.000\.000
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please change the example domain name and IP address accordingly.

**Or**

if you have access to edit web.config then add this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="IP Hit" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="000.000.000.000" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: if you have access to edit web.config then try to my updated answer

Comment: @Rob hello people, from some research i found that shopify plateform does not assign IP for the website. they are hosting multiple sites on their servers..so now, in this case, how can SEO checkup report give the error at this point.  pl help if you know.

Comment: Hi Sonagara, you're correct. Shopify runs off a CDN. All sites are effectively a sub domain of myshopify.com. I'm not that familiar with SEO - but a pal suggested something to do with canonicalizing the root - and then setting up a record for Shopify to run off a subdomain? I really don't know... sorry